# Netbeans 7.2.1 asks for netx.jar and plugin.jar files when debugging

Tags: netbeans, java

How can i fix this issue. It's not causing any problems yet

```
Have no file for /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/netx.jar
Have no file for /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/plugin.jar
```

Linux OS

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same problem.  Fixed it on Ubuntu 12.0.4 by removing the jdk I already had, and going here to install jdk with Netbeans:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-netbeans-jsp-142931.html

Not sure if that is the answer you're looking for, but might work for you.